# Concatenate two customized string objects in C++?

Tags: c++, string, memory, dynamic

I am working on defining my own string class for a homework. It comes to my attention that the following code

```
class MyString {
public:
    MyString(const char* s = NULL) {len = strlen(s); str = new char[len + 1]; strcpy(str, s);}
    ~MyString() {delete [] str;}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& ost, const MyString& s) { ost << s.str; return ost;}
    friend MyString operator + (const MyString &s1, const MyString &s2) { 
        int length = strlen(s1.str) + strlen(s2.str); 

        char *str = new char[length + 1];
        strcpy(str, s1.str);
        strcat(str, s2.str);
        return MyString(str);
    }
private:
    char * str;
    int len;
};

int main () {
    MyString s1 = MyString("hello");
    MyString s2 = MyString("world");
    cout << s1 + s2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

works, as the return object is created at the last moment. But the following code

```
class MyString {
public:
    MyString(const char* s = NULL) {len = strlen(s); str = new char[len + 1]; strcpy(str, s);}
    ~MyString() {delete [] str;}
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& ost, const MyString& s) { ost << s.str; return ost;}
    friend MyString operator + (const MyString &s1, const MyString &s2) { 
        int length = strlen(s1.str) + strlen(s2.str); 
        MyString temp;
        temp.str = new char[length + 1];
        strcpy(temp.str, s1.str);
        strcat(temp.str, s2.str);
        return temp;
    }
private:
    char * str;
    int len;
};

int main () {
    MyString s1 = MyString("hello");
    MyString s2 = MyString("world");
    cout << s1 + s2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Does not, giving me a run time error. So I am confused by why the second approach fails, if a temporary object is defined, modified and returned in the overloaded operator.

Comment: I strongly recommend two things: (1) do not use manual memory mangement; instead, wrap around a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`. (2) Do not use the C string functions. Use C++ standard library algorithms instead (in particular, this would be `std::copy` here.

Comment: `MyString temp;` uses constructor with `s == nullptr`, then `strlen(s)` is UB.

Comment: Watch out: you currently disobey the Rule of Three.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that when you default-construct `temp` here:

```
MyString temp;
```

You have to execute:

```
MyString(const char* s = NULL) {len = strlen(s); ... }
```

`strlen` on a null pointer is undefined. It would work if you instead changed the default argument to:

```
MyString(const char* s = "")
```

---

However, both solutions are still poor in that they both leak memory. In the former, you never `delete[]` the temporary `str`. In the latter, your default constructor allocated a new `str` member, and then you immediately override it with a new allocated `str` member. The original is leaked.

Answer (score 0):

in your constructor you allocate your memory for your string:

```
len = strlen(s); str = new char[len + 1]; strcpy(str, s);
```

so if you append a string later on; there is no memory allocated therefore.

When creating the sum of your two string; you create your "sum-string" like this:

```
MyString temp;
```

then the memory allocated for str is unknown; since

```
len = strlen(NULL);
```

If you want to continue along; you might consider adding two things:

- a check whether s = NULL; then not allocate memory but this will cause trouble later on...
- a method to allocate more memory; something like temp.allocate(strlen(s1) + strlen(s2))

Answer (score 0):

The return is creating an object and copying pointer.  Then  2 deletes occur on same address